# Project is not deploying project in vercel

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

when I deploy my project to vercel its shows me an error.
when I just command enter code here`"npm run build"` in the terminal its shows

> ○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)

but I don't understand what the problem is. Can anyone help me?

```js
PS E:\1.Projects\project-1.1> npm run build

> build     
> next build

info  - Checking validity of types
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data  
[    ] info  - Generating static pages (0/6)undefined
false
info  - Generating static pages (6/6)
info  - Finalizing page optimization

Page                                       Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                      14.2 kB         125 kB
├   /_app                                  0 B            85.2 kB
├ ○ /404                                   194 B          85.4 kB
├ ○ /about                                 2 kB            113 kB
├ ○ /contact                               37.4 kB         148 kB
└ ○ /request-content                       30.1 kB         141 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              85.2 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-6e4ba497ae0c8a3f.js   42 kB
  ├ chunks/main-83803dd478f5b5bc.js        26.9 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-63a5c32e7590e674.js  15.2 kB
  └ chunks/webpack-df4cf1c8d23aa877.js     1.03 kB

○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
```

Comment: What is the error code in the Vercel server log?